# Large data array by WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have wcf-service and wcf-client. Service send to client a big data array - 55000+ items for one request. Forming this array on service-side takes less then one second, but client-side recieve this array more than 5 seconds! Can I faster this? I use BasicHttpBinding on client-side, if in important. (Pagination is not good idea for me)

Comment: Sometimes you can get some improvement by changing the serialization of the items you're returning. For example, if a property is named `SomeLongPropertyName`, specifying `[DataMember(Name = "slpn")] `prevents that entire long property name from appearing in the serialized data. Sometimes the overhead of the member names is far greater than the actual values.

Answer (score 1):

try using `messageEncoding="Mtom"` which must stream your data or if WCF client and server is yours change it to net.tcp binding the lower level protocol will get rid of the overhead data, and with it you could also stream the data